# JavaScript module system and React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-modules

Consider the following simple react app component which is in its own file, App.js and the App component function is exported as default and then imported to main.js file. My question is that why the code other then the App function executes in this file either that be imports or console.log('outside function'). Shouldn't only the code of function should execute when we refer this component in main.js?

```
import Alexa from './alexa.png';
import Siri from './siri.png';
import Cortana from './cortana.png';

console.log(Siri);
console.log(Alexa);
console.log(Cortana);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, React world!!!</h1>
      <img src={Alexa} alt='' />
      <img src={Siri} alt='' />
      <img src={Cortana} alt='' />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Because you're exporting it as **default** that's why. If you have a named export function, then it will only execute that specific function.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  Are you asking why the code you're executing... executes?  The code shown imports three things, logs them to the console, and exports a function.  Is that not the behavior you're seeing or expecting?  What's the actual problem?

Comment: _"Shouldn't only the code of function should execute"_ - no, because on import _all of the code runs_. Here `App` is being defined not called.

Comment: @David yes! I don't expect the code other than the App function to execute because I am only exporting it and referencing this function in main.js file. Why the other code in the module is executing?

Comment: @SaadAli: Because when a JavaScript code file is referenced, it executes.  If you don't expect any of the code shown to execute, why do you expect the `import` and `export` statements to execute?  By what logic would you expect the system to pick and choose which statements it executes and why?  How would this code "export" anything if the top-level statements (which include `export` statements) don't execute?

Comment: @Mani_MR Nope. Importing a module always executes all code in the module. Regardless of how you declare exports.

Comment: @SaadAli Why do you think does the code in your *main.js* file execute?

Comment: Btw this has nothing to do with React.

Comment: @Bergi well I started learning React just recently and even though I went through modules section when going through JS, I observed this just today. I expect the code in main.js file to execute because this is main file and JS thread of execution will execute each line one by one and I was expecting all the code in other modules to be executed, just the function I am calling.

Comment: @Bergi so if we import one module into other javascript file(module) the code inside the module being imported runs before the code of file in which we are importing and we can access the variables/functions that are exported but all code in the module runs if we are importing anything from the module. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @SaadAli Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 1):

When you import a file (and this is equally true of using `require` in node.js) all the top-level statements of that file are evaluated:

```
import React from 'react';

console.log('I will print');
fetch('some-url')
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(json => console.log('I will print the fetched JSON data', json));

const Foo = () => <p>Hello World!</p>;
export default Foo;
```

That's just how Javascript (and almost every other programming language) works. You can even import files solely for their side-effects:

```
// in effectOnly.js
console.log('hello');
// no exports!
```

and in some other file

```
import './effectOnly.js'; // no assignment
```

And you'll see 'hello' in the console.

If you think about it for a second, it actually *has* to be that way: if it wasn't then how could `Foo` be defined in order to be exported if the assignment statement wasn't evaluated?

Comment: "*How could `Foo` be defined in order to be exported if the statement wasn't evaluated?*" - that's true for your `const Foo` to be initialised, but the OP has a `function App(){ … }` which is in fact declared and exported (due to "hoisting") before any code in the module is evaluated.